# How is 1 Timothy 2:5 interpreted relative to the Mediatrix concept?

Tags: catholicism, mariology, intercession-of-saints, mediator

The concept of [Mediatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediatrix) has Virgin Mary in a role of a mediator in the salvation process—at least that's what Wikipedia says:

> Mediatrix in Roman Catholic Mariology refers to the role of the Blessed Virgin Mary as a mediator in the salvation process.

From my admittedly biased point of view, this seems to clash with Paul's writing about Jesus being the only mediator between man and God.

> [**1 Timothy 2:5-6 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1tim%202:5-6&version=ESV)
>    <sup>5</sup> For there is one God, and there is one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus, <sup>6</sup>  who gave himself as a ransom for all, which is the testimony given at the proper time.

What is the Catholic teaching about the Mediatrix concept? How is this passage interpreted? Do all Mariologists take this passage into account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, Catholic theologians are well aware of the Bible verses concerning this teaching.

The EWTN Faith Library article on [Mary, Mediatrix of All Graces](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/teachings/mediatrix-of-all-graces-143) has a fine explanation, under the heading "Objections", that compares the mediation of Christ with the mediation provided by Mary, in light of 1 Tim 3:5.

The Catholic Encyclopedia [article on Mediator](https://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10118a.htm) points out that Jesus' unique mediatorship is concerned with the salvation of mankind, something only He could do. Note that Mary receives no mention here, as the article focuses on salvation and the origin of all graces.

[This article](https://www.catholic.com/qa/isnt-calling-mary-the-mediatrix-of-all-graces-contrary-to-the-doctrine-that-jesus-is-the-sole) on the very topic of your question makes the point that Mary is called a Mediatrix because she is the conduit of the graces that originate through Jesus, first, because her "yes" to God gave us our Savior; second, because she, like all saints, and indeed all Christians, petitions her Son through prayer intentions.

Comment: +1 For pointing out the problem with the question, it's missing the 'of all Graces' part.  Which is the popular, but yet unconfirmed Marian dogma I think dancek is asking about - although it might be good to get clarification.

Comment: @Firstrock Thanks for the great answer, those are good articles indeed. And welcome to Christianity.SE on my behalf! @PeterTurner I was using the definition of `Mediatrix` from Wikipedia, which I explicitly quoted now. Looking at it now, what Wikipedia says in the opening paragraph seems a little misleading.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one Mediator ([1 Tim. 2:5](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=61&ch=2&l=5-#x)) between God and man, Jesus Christ. But Jesus Christ *is* God. So we need a Mediatrix to mediate between Jesus the God-Man and man.

There can be other mediators subjected to Jesus Christ. Think about who brought you to Christ. You didn't do it alone. Saints and angels in heaven plus people on earth can help you through their prayers and actions. These people are your mediators, being subject to the one Mediator.

The Blessed Virgin Mother of God is Mediatrix because without her "Be it done to me according to thy word" ([Luke 1:38](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=49&ch=1&l=38-#x))—her *fiat*—there would be no Christ, no Church, and thus no salvation. She brings us to Christ and Christ to us in a most supreme way than any other creature can.